# DOM appendChild is not works for two variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having the following code to write list element in js click function, for two divs(myList , myList1).

I am appending li child for both, but only second div gets updated but first div is not updated,

```js
 function myFunction() {
   var node = document.createElement("LI");
   var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
   node.appendChild(textnode);
   document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
   document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(node);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <ul id="myList">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="myList1">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>

</html>
```

It produces the following output,

```
myList:
    -------
Coffee
Tea

myList1:
    -------
Coffee
Tea
Water
```

Actual output I am looking for is as follows,

```
myList:
    -------
Coffee
Tea
Water

myList1:
    -------
Coffee
Tea
Water
```

I am missing something here, can someone suggest what it is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *If the node is an existing node in a dom, it will be removed from its old and put to the new position* - js doc

Comment: just give you clear idea see the fiddle actually what happen https://jsfiddle.net/5zmsxem0/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because appendchild moves the node from first to second ul.

this line

```
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
```

add the node to ul **myList** but the very next line

```
document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(node);
```

moves the node from **myList** to **myList1**

You can clone your node to get the desired result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<ul id="myList1">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var node = document.createElement("LI");
   var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
   node.appendChild(textnode);
   var newNode = node.cloneNode(true);
   document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
   document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(newNode);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As your question has a jQuery tag, you should try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  node = $('<li/>').html("water")
  $('ul').append(node)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<ul id="myList1">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant append a node to multiple elems. You need to clone it:

```
var elem=document.createElement("Li");
//add text
elem2=elm.cloneNode(true);
//append to dom
```